# how to create a workbook with `WorkbookFactory` using apache poi 4.1.0

Tags: java, android, xml, apache-poi

I am making an android application using java, I am stuck at using apache poi 4.1.0. The actual problem is that it gives the error `WorkbookFactory not found`.

Comment: Have you declared the dependency of Apache POI in your `build.gradle`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only adding Apache POI dependency wont be enough. For WorkbookFactory you should add poi-ooxml dependency too. Here is what i add in my build.gradle

```
implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi:4.0.0'
implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:4.0.0'
```

Comment: WorkookFactory is been included but there is a new issue    Duplicate class org.apache.poi.EncryptedDocumentException found in modules poi-3.7.jar (poi-3.7.jar) and poi-4.0.0.jar (org.apache.poi:poi:4.0.0)
Duplicate class org.apache.poi.OldFileFormatException found in modules poi-3.7.jar (poi-3.7.jar) and poi-4.0.0.jar (org.apache.poi:poi:4.0.0)
Duplicate class org.apache.poi.POIDocument found in modules poi-3.7.jar (poi-3.7.jar) and poi-4.0.0.jar (org.apache.poi:poi:4.0.0)
Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.